# What happens when a query is fired by client in Impala?

Tags: cloudera, impala

how does the client contact the impalad deamon when a query is fired ?
What exactly happens in the background when a client fires a query which has to be executed by impala ?

Answer (score 1):

Take impala-shell for example, it is a ImpalaShell Python class extends [cmd.Cmd](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html). User will:

1) `connect ip:port` in the shell, which will call `do_connect(..)` and connect to Impala backend through thrift. and a thrift client is created as `self.imp_service = ImpalaService.Client(protocol)`

2) `select xxx from table...` in the shell, which will call `do_select(...)` and `self.imp_service.query(query)` will be called which is a thrfit rpc.

3) Then the rpc query is executed on the Impalad side by `void ImpalaServer::query(QueryHandle&, const Query&)` :

- coordinator parse the query and create a fragmented AST, and assign each fragment to a set of hosts to execute;
- rpc calls are issued in parallel to each host for each fragment.
- parent fragment will wait until child fragment is done.

4) When all fragments are done, data will be shown on the screen after `fetch()` which is a thrift call from client side.